# invoking android to send an e-mail on given time without opening app

Tags: android, email, alarmmanager, schedule

I am making a app which requires me to schedule task. My user can schedule an e-mail body, subject,recipient e-mail address etc and those datas will be saved in internal DB. They will also specify the time and date on which they want the app should send the e-mail and inform them afterwards. I know about AlarmManager but not sure if this can be accomplished with it. Please suggest. Is there any third party library for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AlarmManager to schedule work in background and Check the system date and time with user set date and time. if they met the information then  use this example to send email via background in android.(I do not give you source code because AlarmManager and mail code in internet)

[example to send email in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

Comment: Thanx mate its working. There is a doubt too..will this work with numerous number of job?  how will it react if two different job is schedules on same time or same job on same time?